# Am I missing something ? PHP MYSQL connection through Xammp

Tags: php, html, mysql, xampp

I'm trying to add form data into my database table on Xampp ,but while My echo displays everything properly ,it doesn't input anything into the database table and I wonder if I'm missing something here.I made sure to spell everything the same ,so I doubt it's a spelling error atleast....Any help,suggestions and or corrections are greatly appreciated !

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>  

<?php


// define variables and set to empty values
$VarErr = $PavErr = $AdErr = $PkErr = $KiekErr = "";
$Vardas = $Pavarde = $Adresas = $Pk = $Kiekis = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["Vardas"])) {
    $VarErr = "Įveskite vardą";
  } else {
    $Vardas= test_input($_POST["Vardas"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Vardas)) {
      $VarErr = "Galima vesti tik su raidėmis"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Pavarde"])) {
    $PavErr = "Įveskite pavardę";
  } else {
    $Pavarde = test_input($_POST["Pavarde"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Pavarde)) {
      $PavErr = "Galima vesti tik su raidėmis"; 
    }
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Adresas"])) {
    $AdErr = "Įveskite adresą";
  } else {
    $Adresas= test_input($_POST["Adresas"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Pk"])) {
    $Pk = "Įveskite prekės kodą";
  } else {
    $Pk = test_input($_POST["Pk"]);
  }

  if (empty($_POST["Kiekis"])) {
    $KiekErr = "Įveskite kiekį";
  } else {
    $Kiekis = test_input($_POST["Kiekis"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
?>

<h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
<p><span class="error">* required field</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">  
  Vardas: <input type="text" name="Vardas" value="<?php echo $Vardas;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $VarErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Pavarde: <input type="text" name="Pavarde" value="<?php echo $Pavarde;?>">
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $PavErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Adresas: <input type="text" name="Adresas" value="<?php echo $Adresas;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $AdErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Pk: <input type="number" name="Pk" value="<?php echo $Pk;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $PkErr;?></span>
  <br><br>
  Kiekis:<input type="number" name="Kiekis" value="<?php echo $Kiekis;?>">
  <span class="error"><?php echo $KiekErr;?></span>

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">  
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $Vardas;
echo "<br>";
echo $Pavarde;
echo "<br>";
echo $Adresas;
echo "<br>";
echo $Pk;
echo "<br>";
echo $Kiekis;

$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password ="";
$database = "uzsakymas";

try{
    $connect = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$database);
} 
catch(mysqli_sql_exception $ex){
    echo 'database connection error';
}

if(isset($_POST['insert'])) {

    $Vardas = $_POST['Vardas'];
    $Pavarde = $_POST['Pavarde'];
    $Adresas = $_POST['Adresas'];
    $Pk = $_POST['Pk'];
    $Kiekis = $_POST['Kiekis'];

    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO uzsakymai (Vardas,Pavarde,Adresas,Pk,Kiekis)VALUES('$Vardas','$Pavarde','$Adresas','$Pk','$Kiekis')";
    try {
        $insert_result = mysqli_query($connect,$insert_query);

        if($insert_result){
            if(mysqli_affected_rows($connect) > 0)
            {
                echo 'Data Inserted';
                }else{
                    echo'Data not Inserted';
                }   

            }
        } catch(Exception $ex) {
            echo 'Error Insert'.$ex->getMessmessage();
        }
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). **This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.** Also check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) along the way to make sure everything works as it should.

Comment: I don't see an `insert` in your form. Do you mean to check for `$_POST['submit']`?

Comment: I do not see "insert" in form. Generic:
1. try with SQL query only in phpMyAdmin with any value instead variable.
2. and step by step from your php page.

Answer (score 1):

hi your are checking value in insert `isset($_POST['insert'])` but insert name not assign in any control so assign insert name to your submit control check below :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="insert">
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm kinda confused with your code but I think the wrong part is in here:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
```

You have this submit but look at this:

```
if(isset($_POST['insert']))
```

You are trying to check if POST is set to insert instead of submit.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! After some staring and thinking I figured it out !